# Is there a REST-based JPA provider?

Tags: rest, jpa, provider

A common requirement is to access a JPA DataSource via REST. I want the opposite, i.e. a JPA provider that works by sending HTTP requests to a RESTful persistence service. The benefit of this is that any application written against the JPA API could easily switch between a traditional JPA provider (e.g. Hibernate) and the REST-based JPA provider, with no code changes required.

So my question is whether there is an existing REST-based JPA provider, and if not, would such a thing even be feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datanucleaus has a JPA implementation over a RESTful json API.  However, your REST API must adhere to their conventions:  http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/json/support.html

Their S3 and GoogleStorage extend the json API.

EDIT: Put link to wrong product in my original answer.

Comment: Having read that doco, it looks like a JPA repository exposed via REST, which is the opposite of what I want. I'm looking for a JPA provider that's implemented using HTTP calls to some RESTful persistence service.

Comment: Yeah, my bad.  Datanucleus has a json provider which is what I should have linked.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, JPA is really designed for relational databases...

Second, there is no standard for RESTful persistence so a JPA-REST provider would be specific to that REST persistence application.

You *could* implement something using [EclipseLink-EIS](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EIS_Projects_(ELUG)).  You'd just have to create the JCA_RestAdapter implementation.

If you mean one of the NoSQL databases when you say "RESTful persistence service" then maybe. Some of these NoSQL DBs provide a REST based interface and some JPA providers are starting to support NoSQL DBs. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/NoSQL.

Honestly you'd be better off just implementing the DAO pattern and abstracting your CRUD(L) operations. This is exactly what DAOs are for.

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives out there.  For example, take a look at "JEST":

> https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/pinaki/entry/rest_and_jpa_working_together71?lang=en
>
> REST is not an API (Application Programming Interface). It is an
>   architectural style that prescribes not  to have an API to access the
>   facilities of a service.
>
> ...
>
> On the opposite end of the stateless spectrum lies the principle of
>   JEE Application Servers -- where the server maintains state of
>   everything and there exists one (or multiple) API for everything. Such
>   server-centric, stateful, API-oriented principles of JEE led to
>   several roadblocks.
>
> ...
>
> I found REST principles concise and elegant. I also find Java
>   Persistence API (JPA) providers have done a great job in standardizing
>   and rationalizing the classic object-relational impedance mismatch.
>   JPA is often misconstrued as a mere replacement of JDBC -- but it is
>   much more than JDBC and even more than Object-Relational Mapping
>   (ORM). JPA is be a robust way to view and update relational data as an
>   object graph. Also core JPA notions such as detached transaction  or
>   customizable closure or persistent identity are seemed to neatly
>   aligned with REST principles.

Further links:

- http://openjpa.apache.org/jest.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jest/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: JEST doesn't seem to be a JPA provider; it seems to provide a REST gateway to an OpenJPA data store: "JEST is a REST style access to any OpenJPA runtime." IOW, it's the opposite of what I want, unless I'm missing something?